# What's the symbol for the antiparticle of the $\Delta^+$ baryon?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, terminology, antimatter, notation

It can't be $\Delta^-$ since that is another particle also made up of quarks (not antiquarks). I can think of four possibilities:

1. $\overline\Delta^+$
2. $\overline{\Delta^+}$
3. $\overline\Delta^-$
4. $\overline{\Delta^-}$

I am sure someone has asked a similar question, but I failed at searching for it.

Comment: Are we deciding the future of physics notation? I vote #2.

Comment: Why on earth would an answer to this question be worth a bounty? There's no knowledge to be gained here, it's just about more or less arbitrary notation that doesn't even carry semantics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I'm pretty sure I offered a bounty because there were originally no answers. Also, what do you mean there's no knowledge? Why shouldn't I be bothered by the fact that there's a particle I don't know how to write down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $\Delta$ is a quartet of particles with isospin 3/2:
$$
\Delta^-, \Delta^0, \Delta^+, \Delta^{++}
$$
I would expect the anti-$\Delta$ to be written $\bar\Delta$, with the four isospin projections
$$
\bar\Delta^{--}, \bar\Delta^-, \bar\Delta^0, \bar\Delta^+
$$
In this case the antiparticle of the $\Delta^+$ would be the $\bar\Delta^-$.

If you'd like a canonical reference, look for a paper about pion production with antiproton beams. Note that there's a whole spectrum of $\Delta$ resonances, not just the lightest one at 1232 MeV.

Answer (score 3):

[This graphic](http://www.thingsmadethinkable.com/item/baryons.php) on [Things Made Thinkable](http://www.thingsmadethinkable.com/) uses the $\bar\Delta^-$ notation, which corroborates rob's prediction.