# Charge determines masses?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, isospin-symmetry

Why are the masses of the $\Sigma^-$ ($1197\ \mathrm{MeV}$) and $\Sigma^+$ ($1189\ \mathrm{MeV}$) particles are not exactly equal?

$\Sigma^-$ has quark context $\rm dds$ and $\Sigma^+$ has $\rm uus$...I have been thinking that this has to do with their charge, but I am not sure how that directly relates to mass?

Comment: There is no reason for them to have the same mass: they are not one the antiparticle of the other. Also quark $u$ and $d$ have different masses.

Comment: The particles also differ in lifetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\Sigma^\pm$ are not antiparticles of each other; both are baryons with a single strange quark and nonzero isospin. If [isospin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin) were an exact symmetry then they would have the same mass — but if isospin were an exact symmetry, the proton and neutron would have the same mass as well, and our universe would be very different.

The antiparticle of the $\Sigma^+$ is an antibaryon with quark content $\rm\bar u\bar u\bar s$, and similarly for the $\Sigma^-$.
I'm actually not 100% how to write that particle's name; in the first draft of that sentence I made a different choice than in [this old answer.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137263/44126)